# How to use python on an object in a "for" function in a django template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I want to be able to extract some data in python based on an object in a "for" function in a template.

In the example below I would like to do something with *example* outside the template system, so I wont be limited by the template language, but can instead use python:

```
#django_template.html

{% for example in queryset %}
    #do something to example with python
{% endfor %}
```

I know it might be possible with a template tag, but was wondering if there wasn't a easier way. Is this possible?

EDIT: I am able to do this in the view:

```
for example in queryset:
    #Extract data based on example
```

But the problem is i can't use "{% for example in queryset %}" in the template and then get the data I made for each specific *example* in the view.

Comment: template tag is a nice and very effective way of doing this. if you want a complex tag, you can use some helpers like templatetag-sugar. anither option is to add a method to the 'example' object itself, so it can be called from template

Comment: Yeah maybe i should go the template tag way :) That is maybe the only way around..

Comment: Can you give a more concrete simple example of what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

That's not the way Django works.  If you want to do something "outside" the template language, you do it in your view function.

The template language is intentionally limited to presentation only.

No processing.

(You can fudge the rules a bit with properties and descriptors, but don't.  It ruins performance and confuses the rest of us.  Do you processing in your view functions only, please.)

Comment: I know I should do it in the view. the problem is I don't know how I can tumble with every part of a queryset one at a time in a view and then run through them in the template.

Comment: @tmpethick: "I don't know how I can tumble with every part of a queryset one at a time in a view and then run through them in the template"  First, that's trivial.  That's what generator functions are for.  More importantly, if that's your **real** question, then ask that as a separate question.  Provide details of what concerns you.

Answer (score 0):

If 'example' is an instance of a class that you control, then you can invoke arbitrary class methods within the template, so that if there's something you want to do like using a special pretty printing method, you can call the method by simply inserting `{{example.myfunction}}`.

Beyond that, you cannot write any python code inside the template itself, so the answer to your question as written is no.  You correctly state that you can implement python extensions to the template language using custom tags, however.

Your use of 'calculate data' is a bit scary -- you definitely shouldn't be doing anything remotely heavyweight like math or I/O from a template.  Keep those calculations in your views: this separation is by design.

Comment: I wasn't thinking i could write python within the template.
The problem is that even though it is easy to use "for" in the view and then do something to each instance, it is difficult to then use the "for" in the template and show the different kind of data you got in the view. Dont know if you understand - it is a bit hard to explain :)